# CABasicAnimation with CALayer.affineTransform not working

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have below code specifed as a orbit and planet demo:

```
    _orbitLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);
    _orbitLayer.position = center;
    _orbitLayer.cornerRadius = radius;
    _orbitLayer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    _orbitLayer.borderWidth = 1.5;
    if ([_orbitLayer superlayer]) {
        [_orbitLayer removeAllAnimations];
        [_orbitLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
    [self.layer insertSublayer:_orbitLayer above:_stripeLayer];

    // planet circyle
    _dotCircyleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, (arcWidth - 10),(arcWidth - 10));
    CGPoint anchor_center = CGPointMake(_orbitLayer.bounds.size.width,
                                        _orbitLayer.bounds.size.height/2);
    _dotCircyleLayer.position = anchor_center;
    _dotCircyleLayer.cornerRadius = (arcWidth - 10)/2;
    _dotCircyleLayer.backgroundColor = anchorColor.CGColor;
    if ([_dotCircyleLayer superlayer])
        [_dotCircyleLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [_orbitLayer addSublayer:_dotCircyleLayer];
    _orbitLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startAngle);

// animation
    CABasicAnimation *arcAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"affineTransform"];
    arcAnimation.duration = 0.8;
    arcAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startAngle)];
    arcAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endAngle)];
    arcAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [_orbitLayer addAnimation:arcAnimation forKey:nil];
```

I could rotate this orbit to simulate planet circyling by `_orbitLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startAngle);`
But I cannot animate `_orbitLayer.affineTransform`. My animation code does not work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: try this  `CABasicAnimation *arcAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"]; `

Comment: not working, even if `affineTransform`

Comment: No, I tried these three one, no one works

Comment: it is transform.rotation, but should not use [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endAngle)];

Comment: see this u have to specify correct KeyPath for basic animation  http://www.adamzucchi.com/blog/?p=24

Comment: yes, main reason is I calculated wrongly, I have post the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, use

`arcAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endAngle];`

and

`CABasicAnimation *arcAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];`

saved my day

```
_orbitLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startAngle);
CABasicAnimation *arcAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
arcAnimation.duration = 0.8;
//    arcAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startAngle)];
//    arcAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endAngle)];
    arcAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:startAngle];
    arcAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endAngle];
    arcAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [_orbitLayer addAnimation:arcAnimation forKey:nil];
```